# Exists filter or action that change Add New Post link?

Tags: posts, filters, actions, links

I want to know if exists some method from filters or actions to change the link of the Add New button in backend , for example the regular url is `http://wordpress_install/wp-admin/post-new.php` but I want to add an get parameter `http://localsite/wp4/wp-admin/post-new.php?param=value`. How to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using the admin_url filter:

```
function add_new_post_url( $url, $path, $blog_id ) {

    if ( $path == "post-new.php" ) {
        $path = "post-new.php?param=value";
    }

    return $path;
}
add_filter( 'admin_url', 'add_new_post_url', 10, 3 );
```